# Vba web scrape "a href" .click

Tags: vba, excel, href

```
<tr ><th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="abdelal01" data-stat="player" ><a href="/players/a/abdelal01.html">Alaa Abdelnaby</a></th><td class="right " data-stat="year_min" >1991</td><td class="right " data-stat="year_max" >1995</td><td class="center " data-stat="pos" >F-C</td><td class="right " data-stat="height" csk="82.0" >6-10</td><td class="right " data-stat="weight" >240</td><td class="left " data-stat="birth_date" csk="19680624" ><a href="/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=6&amp;day=24">June 24, 1968</a></td><td class="left " data-stat="college_name" ><a href="/friv/colleges.cgi?college=duke">Duke University</a></td></tr>

<tr ><th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="abdulza01" data-stat="player" ><a href="/players/a/abdulza01.html">Zaid Abdul-Aziz</a></th><td class="right " data-stat="year_min" >1969</td><td class="right " data-stat="year_max" >1978</td><td class="center " data-stat="pos" >C-F</td><td class="right " data-stat="height" csk="81.0" >6-9</td><td class="right " data-stat="weight" >235</td><td class="left " data-stat="birth_date" csk="19460407" ><a href="/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=4&amp;day=7">April 7, 1946</a></td><td class="left " data-stat="college_name" ><a href="/friv/colleges.cgi?college=iowast">Iowa State University</a></td></tr>

<tr ><th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="abdulka01" data-stat="player" ><a href="/players/a/abdulka01.html">Kareem Abdul-Jabbar</a>*</th><td class="right " data-stat="year_min" >1970</td><td class="right " data-stat="year_max" >1989</td><td class="center " data-stat="pos" >C</td><td class="right " data-stat="height" csk="86.0" >7-2</td><td class="right " data-stat="weight" >225</td><td class="left " data-stat="birth_date" csk="19470416" ><a href="/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=4&amp;day=16">April 16, 1947</a></td><td class="left " data-stat="college_name" ><a href="/friv/colleges.cgi?college=ucla">University of California, Los Angeles</a></td></tr>

<tr ><th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="abdulma02" data-stat="player" ><a href="/players/a/abdulma02.html">Mahmoud Abdul-Rauf</a></th><td class="right " data-stat="year_min" >1991</td><td class="right " data-stat="year_max" >2001</td><td class="center " data-stat="pos" >G</td><td class="right " data-stat="height" csk="73.0" >6-1</td><td class="right " data-stat="weight" >162</td><td class="left " data-stat="birth_date" csk="19690309" ><a href="/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=3&amp;day=9">March 9, 1969</a></td><td class="left " data-stat="college_name" ><a href="/friv/colleges.cgi?college=lsu">Louisiana State University</a></td></tr>

<tr ><th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="abdulta01" data-stat="player" ><a href="/players/a/abdulta01.html">Tariq Abdul-Wahad</a></th><td class="right " data-stat="year_min" >1998</td><td class="right " data-stat="year_max" >2003</td><td class="center " data-stat="pos" >F</td><td class="right " data-stat="height" csk="78.0" >6-6</td><td class="right " data-stat="weight" >223</td><td class="left " data-stat="birth_date" csk="19741103" ><a href="/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=11&amp;day=3">November 3, 1974</a></td><td class="left " data-stat="college_name" ><a href="/friv/colleges.cgi?college=sanjosest">San Jose State University</a></td></tr>
```

hi

i need to click every players a links

my code need little help

```
For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementById("players").getElementsByTagName("a")
```

thx

Comment: What is the full code, and what are the issues?

Comment: Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question")

Answer (score 0):

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Dim anchors As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim anchor As HTMLAnchorElement
Set anchors = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each anchor In anchors
    ' anchor.Click ... this probably won't work

    ' I gues something like this is what you want (untested code)
    ie.navigate anchor.href, 1 ' BrowserNavConstants.navOpenInNewTab
Next anchor
```

See [BrowserNavConstants Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565688(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

i think anchor doesnt work for me or i dont complete :(

result must be 
http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdelal01.html
http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdulza01.html
etc

my fully code

```
Sub basketballreference()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim elealphabet As Object
Dim eleplayertable As Object

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim letter As String
Dim MyString As String
Dim MyLetter As String

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.navigate "http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/"
objIE.Visible = True

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

For Each elealphabet In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("alphabet inline")

MyString = Replace(elealphabet.textContent, "X", "")

'Close all opened ie browser
Dim objWMI As Object, objProcess As Object, objProcesses As Object
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://.")
Set objProcesses = objWMI.ExecQuery( _
"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'iexplore.exe'")
Dim j As Integer
j = objProcesses.Count
For Each objProcess In objProcesses
If j > 1 Then Shell "taskkill /f /PID " & CStr(objProcess.ProcessID), vbHide

j = j - 1
Next
Set objProcesses = Nothing
Set objWMI = Nothing
Set objIE = Nothing

For i = 2 To Len(MyString)
MyLetter = LCase(Mid(MyString, i, 1))

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.navigate "http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/" & MyLetter & "/"
objIE.Visible = True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

For Each eleplayertable In objIE.document.getElementById("players").getElementsByTagName("a")
'must go to players page

Next
Next i
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

2 years to answer :)

Try this if you still got the issue

```
Set elemCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(2)
'Debug.Print elemCollection.Length
'Debug.Print elemCollection.body.innerHTML


For Each tagx In tags
      If tagx.href = "your href" Then
    tagx.Click

End If
Next
```

Hope this helps

Best Regards

Sameur